# Cannot resolve constructor 'Stage(com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport, com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch)'

Tags: android-studio, libgdx, viewport, scene2d, spritebatch

I am beginner in libgdx . When trying to make a game I get this error in Android Studio :

> Error:(39, 16) Gradle: error: no suitable constructor found for
>   Stage(Viewport,SpriteBatch) constructor Stage.Stage() is not
>   applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>   constructor Stage.Stage(StageStyle) is not applicable (actual and
>   formal argument lists differ in length)

-

```
public class Hud {
|  public Stage stage;
|  private Viewport viewport;
|  
|  private Integer worldTimer;
|  private float timeCount;
|  private Integer score;
|  
|  Label countdownLabel;
|  Label scoreLabel;
|  Label timeLabel;
|  Label levelLabel;
|  Label worldLabel;
|  Label snakeLabel;
|  
|  public Hud(SpriteBatch sb) {
|  |  worldTimer = 300;
|  |  timeCount = 0;
|  |  score = 0;
|  |  
|  |  viewport = new FitViewport(Snake.V_WIDTH, Snake.V_HEIGHT, new OrthographicCamera());
|  |  stage = new Stage(viewport,sb);    
|  }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
stage = new Stage(viewport,sb);
```

I searched the internet some solution but I have not found anything. I'm a little lost.
Excuse me for my bad english :)
I hope you can help me . I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong Stage class imported, it should be:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage
```

But you probably have this or some other package:

```
javafx.stage.Stage
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! I can finally continue my game :)